# Handling fraction characters in mysql table

Tags: mysql

My database table has a field (AverageTime) defined as varchar(255) that has text as indicated below (I cut and pasted them from mysql). I can see how I can parse the text (eg. days, hours etc) but I am stuck at handling the fractional characters...I would like to turn them into decimal for analysis (eg. 5.5, 16.5 etc). BTW, the only fraction character I can eyeball in the data is 1/2, so if there is a simple way to convert to decimal based on this observation, that will work for me as well.

```
2 days
5½ hours
2½ days
1 day
17½ hours
1 day
16½ hours
18½ hours
1½ days
14½ hours
```

Comment: Try a simple text replace from '½' to '.5'

Comment: Why is the data being saved as `5½` in the first place?

Comment: Following the suggested string replacement to `.5`, you can `CAST()` the entire thing like `'14.5 hours'` to a plain hour value like `CAST('14.5 hours' AS DECIMAL(10,1))` yielding just 14.5

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I am not convinced that stuff like parsing or interpreting input should happen in the database, as it is pretty fragile assuming there could be subtile format variations.

Comment: @elusive Nor am I, but if it is verified that all records look like the sample, it can be done.  That data should never have been in the database to begin with, and that's why the OP is here.